# Extend nested Selectors/Rules to the parent Selector

Tags: css, syntax, less

I try to write my CSS into Less. I know about the [extend-feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) , but I think, it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

THE Less:

```
nav ul {
  &:extend(.inline);
  background: blue;
}
.inline {
  color: red;
}
```

THE CSS Output:

```
nav ul {
  background: blue;
}
.inline,
nav ul {
  color: red;
}
```

**What I'm looking for:**

My CSS:

```
.nav ul {
    color: red;
    background: blue;
}
.nav ul .inline {
    color: red;
}
```

My Less

```
.nav ul {
    background: blue;
    color: red;
    .inline {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Is there a sensible way to omit the first `color: red;` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the parent selector and nesting like in the below snippet:

```
.nav ul {
    background: blue;
    &, .inline {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

This when compiled would produce the below CSS which is equivalent to your required output.

```
.nav ul {
  background: blue;
}
.nav ul,
.nav ul .inline {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's it and so simple that I'm not even thought of it